# Angular6 - Component in Array Not Updating

Tags: angular

Here is code showing the bug:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbn3kr

I am trying to dynamically update a total quantity field. I created a Quantity Component which is an input that takes in a number and stores that number. In my app component, I have an array of these Quantity Components. When I try QuantityComponent.getQuantity() from the app component, it is always returning 0 even though I know I am correctly setting the components quantity because the components quantities are correctly displaying.

I assume that this is because my QuantityComponent in the array is not being updated. Is my assumption right? How would you code this?

Comment: you are instantiate the component again inside your service thats why quantity gets 0

Comment: why are you set the this.totalQuantity = 0; inside the keyup event method that's why you are getting zero

Comment: You could try using event emitters, as they may simplify some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your are creating new object of `Quantity` in your service. And in the View of App, you are Initiating two other independent instances of quantity. Whenever you use the component selector `<quantity...>`(like you did in app-component-html) angular instantiates the component. I have resolved it in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2oba38)

But you can enhance this by using EventEmitters which would better up the performance. I tried to stick with the idea that you had used that is why you would find a `For-loop` to get TOTAL value, but prefered way would be EventEmitters.

Comment: Also, please note that you have used the 'keyup' event to track the value changes, working with the 'Up' and 'Down' arrows won't get a new value.

Comment: Given that, maybe just use `[(ngModel)]="quantity"` on your input instead, like this example: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#edit-the-hero

Comment: Thank you! I did not expect that using the selector would instantiate a new component. I see that you got a reference to the QuantityComponents in the view with @ViewChildren(QuantityComponent). Is there a way to create the quantity components returned from the service in the view though?

Comment: You can refer to ViewContainerRef https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef. But may i know why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am just thinking of future applications when I may need to create a component in a service and then display it on my view. Thank you for the help.